# What is je_free function in libc.so?

Tags: android, c, libc

Could somebody please explain me what is je_free function defined in libc.so and when is it called?

Note1: while investigating one crash reported in our application, I see application code is directly going to je_free. I dont see je_free is explicitly called in application code.

Note2: Platform: android arm

Comment: Why do you wonder? Where did you hear or read about this function? Is this plain curiosity (which is fine, but please state so in the question itself) or do you have an underlying problem you need to solve (in which case you should ask about that underlying and actual problem directly instead)?

Comment: You are probably looking at a libc that uses [jemalloc](https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc). `je_free` is internal to the implementation.

Comment: @Kaylum, Thanks!! I will go through the link

Comment: @Pendyala: What version of Android is the device running?